# Ansible issue while running sed command

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Trying to run a command in Azure VM via Ansible and Azure cli command but getting template issue

```
- name: Disable disk expansion   
   shell: |     az vm run-command invoke -g {{ resource_group_name }} -n {{ instance_name }} --command-id RunShellScript --scripts "{{ 'sed -i \'/gp/s/\^/#/g\' /etc/config.cfg' }}"
```

Error

> azure-arm.teracloud-azure-arm:   msg: 'template error while templating
> string: unexpected char ''\'' at 142. String: az vm run-command
> invoke -g {{ resource_group_name }} -n {{ instance_name }}
> --command-id RunShellScript --scripts "{{ ''sed -i \''/gp/s/\^/#/g\'' /etc/config.cfg'' }}"'

Comment: This is not really azure related. removing the tag

Answer (score 2):

I do not think you really want to have `{{` `}}` for your `--scripts` part as makes Jinja interpret this as variables to be replaced. Also The "escape madness" you applied to your `sed` command is unnecessary and it should suffice to have it just like `--scripts "sed -i '/gp/s/^/#/g' /etc/config.cfg"`:

```
- name: Disable disk expansion
  shell: |
    az vm run-command invoke -g {{ resource_group_name }} -n {{ instance_name }} --command-id RunShellScript --scripts "sed -i '/gp/s/^/#/g' /etc/config.cfg"
```